# How to select @ElementCollection attribute with Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
data class PieEntity(
        @get:Column
        var name: String = "name",

        @get:Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @get:ElementCollection
        var ingredients: MutableSet<PieIngredient> = mutableSetOf(PieIngredient.A, PieIngredient.B),

        // lots of other properties...

        @get:Id
        @get:GeneratedValue
        var id: Long? = null)

enum class PieIngredient { A, B, C }
```

Now I would like to only select a subset of its attributes, in this case the `name` and `ingredients` attributes.

Currently I found 4 possible solutions, but all of them have flaws:

**Solution 1**

Use class-based projection:

```
data class PiePreviewDto(
    val name: String,
    val ingredients: PieIngredient)

@Repository
interface PieRepository : JpaRepository<PieEntity, Long> {
    fun findTop3ByOrderByNameDesc(): List<PiePreviewDto>
}
```

This creates a select statement which only selects the desired attributes.

The Problem here is that I get one result per pie per ingredient. For example if I have 2 pies with 2 ingredients each, I get 4 results, which means I have to merge these results manually, which seems undesirable.

**Solution 2**

Use projection:

```
interface PiePreview {
    val name: String
    val ingredients: MutableSet<PieIngredient>
}

@Repository
interface PieRepository : JpaRepository<PieEntity, Long> {
    fun findTop3ByOrderByNameDesc(): List<PiePreview>
}
```

Here I get one result per pie (which is good).

The problem is that it actually selects all attributes and I have some "lobs" which I don't want to select (thus exactly this question).

**Solution 3**

Use byte code weaving, so that I can lazy fetch everything (even `@Basic` properties).

I didn't try this since it seems to be vendor specific. However I'm willing to give it a try if this is the most sane solution.

**Solution 4**

Duplicate attributes with converters and class-based projection:

```
@Entity
data class PieEntity(
        @get:Column
        var name: String = "name",

        @get:Convert(converter = PieIngredientSetConverter::class)
        var ingredients: MutableSet<PieIngredient> = mutableSetOf(A, B),

        @get:Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @get:ElementCollection
        var ingredientSet: MutableSet<PieIngredient> = mutableSetOf(A, B),

        // lots of other properties...

        @get:Id
        @get:GeneratedValue
        var id: Long? = null)

class PieIngredientSetConverter : AttributeConverter<MutableSet<PieIngredient>, String> {
    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: MutableSet<PieIngredient>) =
            attribute.joinToString(",") { it.name }

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: String) =
            dbData.split(PATTERN).map { PieIngredient.valueOf(it) }.toMutableSet()
}

data class PiePreviewDto(
    val name: String,
    val ingredients: MutableSet<PieIngredient>)

@Repository
interface PieRepository : JpaRepository<PieEntity, Long> {
    fun findTop3ByOrderByNameDesc(): List<PiePreviewDto>
}
```

This selects only the attributes I want.

The problems are that I have to manually synchronize the duplicated attributes, it uses more disk space (not really a problem in my case) and it needs to be converted.

I need the `ingredientSet` attribute since I perform `IN` queries (search for ingredients).

---

Are there better/improved solutions?